# CUDA binary search implementation

Tags: cuda, nvidia, binary-search

I am trying to speed up the CPU binary search. Unfortunately, GPU version is always much slower than CPU version. Perhaps the problem is not suitable for GPU or am I doing something wrong ?

CPU version (approx. 0.6ms):
using sorted array of length 2000 and do binary search for specific value

```
...
Lookup ( search[j], search_array, array_length, m );
...
int Lookup ( int search, int* arr, int length, int& m )
{      
   int l(0), r(length-1);
   while ( l <= r ) 
   {
      m = (l+r)/2;      
      if ( search < arr[m] )
         r = m-1;
      else if ( search > arr[m] )
         l = m+1;
      else
      {         
         return index[m];
      }         
   }
   if ( arr[m] >= search )
      return m;
   return (m+1);      
}
```

GPU version (approx. 20ms):
using sorted array of length 2000 and do binary search for specific value

```
....
p_ary_search<<<16, 64>>>(search[j], array_length, dev_arr, dev_ret_val);
....

__global__ void p_ary_search(int search, int array_length, int *arr, int *ret_val ) 
{
   const int num_threads = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
   const int thread = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   int set_size = array_length;

   ret_val[0] = -1; // return value
   ret_val[1] = 0;  // offset

   while(set_size != 0)
   {
      // Get the offset of the array, initially set to 0
      int offset = ret_val[1];

      // I think this is necessary in case a thread gets ahead, and resets offset before it's read
      // This isn't necessary for the unit tests to pass, but I still like it here
      __syncthreads();

      // Get the next index to check
      int index_to_check = get_index_to_check(thread, num_threads, set_size, offset);

      // If the index is outside the bounds of the array then lets not check it
      if (index_to_check < array_length)
      {
         // If the next index is outside the bounds of the array, then set it to maximum array size
         int next_index_to_check = get_index_to_check(thread + 1, num_threads, set_size, offset);
         if (next_index_to_check >= array_length)
         {
            next_index_to_check = array_length - 1;
         }

         // If we're at the mid section of the array reset the offset to this index
         if (search > arr[index_to_check] && (search < arr[next_index_to_check])) 
         {
            ret_val[1] = index_to_check;
         }
         else if (search == arr[index_to_check]) 
         {
            // Set the return var if we hit it
            ret_val[0] = index_to_check;
         }
      }

      // Since this is a p-ary search divide by our total threads to get the next set size
      set_size = set_size / num_threads;

      // Sync up so no threads jump ahead and get a bad offset
      __syncthreads();
   }
}
```

Even if I try bigger arrays, the time ratio is not any better.

Comment: A simple binary search isn't exactly ammenable to GPU operations. It's a serial operation that can't be parallelized. However, you could split the array into small chunks and do binary searches on each of those. Create X chunks, determine which might contain your variable in X parallel threads. Toss out all but a candidate, subdivide further, etc...

Comment: You might want to check out Thrust binary search at http://wiki.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/html/group__binary__search.html

Answer (score 1):

You have way too many divergent branches in your code so you're essentially serializing the entire process on the GPU. You want to break up the work so that all the threads in the same warp take the same path in the branch. See page 47 of the [CUDA Best Practices Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_3/toolkit/docs/NVIDIA_CUDA_BestPracticesGuide_2.3.pdf).

Comment: I used array of 2000 elements. And used the CPU version of binary search for number 395. On my PC it tooks only 0.000933ms. For test I created kernel<<<2000,1>>> and leaved the kernel doing absolutely nothing : __global__ void Search (  ) 
{      
   int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;   
   if ( tid < 2000 )
   {
   }
} and just calling this it tooks 0.034704 ms. From this results I am really wondering if it make sense to use CUDA in order to make things faster. Or am I doing something wrong ...

Comment: It really is like that, CUDA as some overhead that takes a bit of time but, when you are doing things that take, for example, 10 seconds on a CPU and the GPU can make it 10 times faster even if it has 0.03s of overhead which one would you prefer? CUDA definitely works but it might not be worth it if on CPU it is already very fast.

Comment: thanks. I will try to transfer more work from PC on GPU and I hope this will remedy somehow the existing overhead. I thought that without memory copying between CPU and GPU, the overhead will already be minimal, but obviously not. I will check also the "thrust" binary search.

Answer (score 0):

I'm must admit I'm not entirely sure what what your kernel does, but am I right in assuming that you are looking for just one index that satisfies your search criteria? If so then have a look at the reduction sample that comes with CUDA for some pointers on how to structure and optimize such a query. (What your are doing is essentially trying to reduce the closest index to your query)

Some quick pointers though:

You are performing an awful lot of reads and writes to global memory, which is incredibly slow. Try using shared memory instead.

Secondly remember that __syncthreads() only syncs threads in the same block, so your reads/writes to global memory won't necessarily get synced across all threads (though the latency from you global memory writes may actually make it appear as if they do)